# Splitting a screen in HTML webpage

Tags: html

need to build a web page which is split.
How can I split screen into 5 different areas:

```
North, 
South, 
East, 
West and Center .
```

how can I do it in HTML PAGE ?

Comment: try http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

**HTML (within body)**

```
<div id="North">
    North Area
</div>
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="West">
        West Area
    </div>
    <div id="Center">
        Center Area
    </div>
    <div id="East">
        East Area
    </div>
</div>
<div id="South">
    South Area
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#North,#Wrapper,#South
{
    width: 100%;
}

#Center,#East,#West
{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

body
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

The north, south, and Wrapper and just fullwidth objects, where the north is on top, and south is below the rest of the content. Then, west, east, and center are just set to each be 33% of the screen width within their area, so they sit nicely next to each other.

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLr824vv/)

Comment: i dont see the page splited all it shows : is regular text line above line

Comment: All of that text exists within splits. Check the DOM setup with your inspector.